# Binary Tree - Depth-First Traversal

Tags: javascript, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I want to do a depth-first traversal for this binary tree:

```
          1
         / \
        4   5
       / \   \
      4   4   5
```

Here's the node structure:

```
function TreeNode(data){
    this.data = data
    this.left = this.right = []

    this.addLeft = function(node){
        this.left.push(node)
    }

    this.addRight = function(node){
        this.right.push(node)
    }
}
```

The visit function (just to print out the node data):

```
function visit(node){
    console.log(node.data)
}
```

The traverse function:

```
function traverse(node){
   if(node === null) return

   visit(node)

   //visit left branch
   for(node of node.left) traverse(node)

   //visit right branch
   for(node of node.right) traverse(node)
}
```

Add the binary tree structure:

```
let rootNode = new TreeNode(1)
let node_4A = new TreeNode(4)
let node_4B = new TreeNode(4)
let node_4C = new TreeNode(4)
let node_5A = new TreeNode(5)
let node_5B = new TreeNode(5)

//add root node branches
rootNode.addLeft(node_4A)
rootNode.addRight(node_5A)

node_4A.addLeft(node_4B)
node_4A.addRight(node_4C)
node_5A.addRight(node_5B)
```

The output:

```
1
4
4
4
5
5
5
```

So it correctly prints out the node data, but there's always an additional right-most node that got printed twice (i.e. the last `5`). Do you have any idea why it happens?

I'm not too familiar with Javascript call stack, but could the reason be I'm running 2 `for` loops in a recursive function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You take the same object reference for left and right.

```
this.left = this.right = []
```

You need independent arrays:

```
this.left = [];
this.right = [];
```

For taking the right node, take different names than `node` for iterating.

```
function traverse(node) {
    if (!node) return;  // you never have a value of null for a node
    visit(node)

    //visit left branch
    for (let n of node.left) {
        traverse(n);
    }
    //visit right branch
    for (let n of node.right) {
        traverse(n);
    }
}
```

```js
function TreeNode(data) {
    this.data = data
    this.left = [];
    this.right = [];

    this.addLeft = function (node) {
        this.left.push(node)
    }

    this.addRight = function (node) {
        this.right.push(node)
    }
}

function visit(node) {
    console.log(node.data)
}

function traverse(node) {
    if (!node) return; // you never have a value of null for a node

    visit(node)

    for (let n of node.left) {
        traverse(n);
    }

    for (let n of node.right) {
        traverse(n);
    }
}

let rootNode = new TreeNode(1)
let node_4A = new TreeNode(4)
let node_4B = new TreeNode(4)
let node_4C = new TreeNode(4)
let node_5A = new TreeNode(5)
let node_5B = new TreeNode(5)

//add root node branches
rootNode.addLeft(node_4A)
rootNode.addRight(node_5A)

node_4A.addLeft(node_4B)
node_4A.addRight(node_4C)
node_5A.addRight(node_5B)
traverse(rootNode);
```

Comment: and the last 5 printed?

Comment: Answer is accepted. Thank you. So I made 2 mistakes, first is using the same reference for `left` and `right` arrays, and second is using the same variable name in the `traverse` function. Is `let` necessary? Because I find that the code runs fine:

      `for(currentNode of node.left) traverse(currentNode)`

I don't use `let`. Would it be a problem later?

Comment: No it isnt even a problem right now, but it makes the code unreadable + error prone + hard to maintain in the future

Answer (score 1):

> DFS (depth first search) is usually easy to implement using recursion. refer to this function definition in js language -

```
    const recFnc = (currNode) => {
      if (currNode !== null) {
        if (currNode.lNode !== null) {
          recFnc(currNode.lNode, lPath);
        }
        if (currNode.rNode !== null) {
          recFnc(currNode.rNode, rPath);
        }
      }
    };

    recFnc(rootNode);
```

Refer to this class I have created - https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dsinjs/binary-tree
and Refer to this function documentation which deals with path calculations and more - https://dsinjs.github.io/binary-tree/#find

Answer (score 0):

You do this:

```
 this.left = this.right = []
```

So the left leaf is actually the same as the right one. You want:

```
 this.left = [];
 this.right = [];
```

---

Just for fun: This would actually be a good usecase for generators:

```
 TreeNode.prototype.leftFirst = function*() {
    yield this.data;
    for(const child of this.left.concat(this.right))
       yield* child.leftFirst();
 };
```

So you can do:

```
 for(const node of tree.leftFirst())
    console.log(node);
```

Comment: Correct. That's my mistake of using the same object reference. What is the `*` after `function`?

Comment: @daniel that turns the function into a *generator function*